# How to fix double slash for PHP?

Tags: php

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Options -MultiViews
AcceptPathInfo On

# multiviews functionality
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/?)(.*?)$ $1.php$2$3 [L]

# 1)
# https://www.example.com/city-name/...
# must rewrite to
# https://www.example.com/index/city-name

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/?$ index/$1 [NC]

# 2)
# https://www.example.com/city-name/list/category-name/[n,s,c,a]-9-13-1
# must rewrite to
# https://www.example.com/list/city-name/category-name/[n,s,c,a]-9-13-1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/list/([a-z0-9-]+)/([nsca0-9-]+)$ list/$1/$2/$3 [NC]

# 3)
# https://www.example.com/city-name/place/01234/rosemarys-enoteca-trattoria
# must rewrite to
# https://www.example.com/place/01234/rosemarys-enoteca-trattoria

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/place/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]*)$ place/$2 [NC]
```

My PHP pages are not working, resulting in

```
https://www.example.com//user/login
```

Please help how to fix .htaccess?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please include a precise description of actual vs expected behavior.

Comment: these regex patterns provide little meaning and also the rewrite destinations; you'd have to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping those slashes, your server is probably interpreting them as comments.